# Codeigniter not displaying validation_errors()

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

**SOLUTION: I used WAMP server on my VPS. The problem was the rewrite module was not loaded in the apache settings. I fixed this by going into my apache folder/conf/http.conf and removing the hashtag infront of this line: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. I restarted apache and it worked.**

EDIT: It's not running even tho i input an email and password. I am not being able to run the form_validation at all it seems.

EDIT 2: Also found out i can't echo $this->input->post('email'); in the function login_validation.

EDIT 3: I echoed out $this->output->enable_profiler(); and it said i sent no post data. Is it possible that my .htaccess is doing something with the posting?

i'm creating a login / registration system using codeigniter. I got it to work on localhost but something must have happened when i moved it to my host.

I autoload form in my autoload.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

This is my validation code in class Main file controllers/main.php:

```
public function login_validation(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //NO VALIDATION ERRORS
    }else{
        echo 'Errors:<br />';
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

My form:

```
<?php 
echo form_open('main/login_validation');

$property_type = array('class' => 'bar left', 'value' => 'E-Mail', 'name' => 'email');
echo form_input($property_type);

$property_type = array('class' => 'bar right', 'value' => 'Password', 'name' => 'password');
echo form_password($property_type);

$property_type = array('class' => 'buttonone', 'value' => 'Login', 'name' => 'login_submit');
echo form_submit($property_type);

echo form_close(); 
?>
```

When i dont type in anything in the form it should display Email and password is required. It only says Errors:. But it does not display the validation errors.

I also had to change to another .htaccess when i uploaded it to my host.

This is my new htaccess:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This is my old .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used WAMP server on my VPS. The problem was the rewrite module was not loaded in the apache settings. I fixed this by going into my apache folder/conf/http.conf and removing the hashtag infront of this line: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. I restarted apache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just check the if condition and put form error function in to view page

public function login_validation(){

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

      if ($this->form_validation->run($this) !== FALSE) //write like this if condition
      { 
        //NO VALIDATION ERRORS
    }else{
        echo 'Errors:<br />';
        echo validation_errors();
    }
}
```

your view page put in to this

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

more refer this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html